# AWS Athena SQL view to conditionally query tables based on where condition

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I tried to create an Athena table with 1700+ partitions where each partition has 100 buckets (not S3 buckets but Athena buckets, which are like hashes on top of high cardinality columns to speed up queries). Unfortunately I learned that Athena doesn't support more than 100 partitions, and if you use their workaround to support more than 100 partitions, you can't use any buckets. So then I thought, what if I made each partition its own separate table? Then I could give each table its own 100 buckets. The idea is that I would hide all of these tables under a SQL view. When the user specifies a partition, the view would pick the correct table, and query only that table. That led me to post this question.

How can I make a SQL view in Athena that conditionally queries tables? At first I thought it would be simple, but now I'm realizing it's not. I could naively union all the tables, and then run the condition on the unioned result, but that would defeat the purpose of the partitions because I would end up reading all of the data all the time. Is what I'm describing possible?

I want to do this but without the union:

```
CREATE VIEW example AS (
SELECT col1, col2, 1 as partition FROM partition1
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, 2 as partition FROM partition2)
```

Where the user would specify something like:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM example
WHERE partition = 1
```

Comment: Do you really need 1,700 partitions? I believe that you will be surprised to see that going one level up the partition structure (hour to day, or day to month) makes it much simpler to manage and doesn't hurt performance in most cases.

Comment: Yeah, I do really need 1,700 partitions. Each partition is already 25 GB. This is a genomics use case. A single person has 300 GB of data. I'm not partitioning by person but rather chromsome and some other more obscure genomics low cardinality columns (exon, junction, etc). I don't want to needlessly scan data (and incur a larger AWS bill for doing so) if I can avoid it.

Comment: Did you compress the data in S3? Please remember that the scanning cost is on the compressed version of it as well.

Comment: Yeah, the data is gzipped compressed. I suppose I could convert it to a better, perhaps more columnar format like parquet, but I'd still like to avoid scanning the whole column / file if I can avoid it.

Comment: You can have more than 100 partitions (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html):
Although Athena supports querying AWS Glue tables that have 10 million partitions, Athena cannot read more than 1 million partitions in a single scan.

If you are not using AWS Glue Data Catalog, the default maximum number of partitions per table is 20,000. You can request a quota increase.